# how to set image type column to null in sql server using parameters in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I tried to set the parameter value to system.dbnull.value but got some errors. 
thanks.

Comment: Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image...

Comment: Show us the code where you set the parameters, and the sql, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that SQLServer is reading the NULL type as nvarchar, which cannot be used to update an Image column.

Try specifying the Parameter Type as SqlDbType.Image

```
SqlParameter myParam = new SqlParameter("@NameOfParameter",SqlDbType.Image);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to not use a parameter when you're setting it to null. Instead, you can hardcode '=null' in the SQL command and skip parameters completely.

Comment: This works, but he might be coding this into his datalayer and wants to be able t o set the correct parameter value.